# Share environment variables between two containers from docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

In docker compose, I have two containers, one named `php-container`, the other `nginx`. For the NGINX container, I defined an environment variable.
Is there a way to access that variable in the PHP container? I want to access the `PLAYER_NAME` variable in my PHP container

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build: '.'
    volumes:
      - './:/srv/api:rw'
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - backend

  nginx_player_1:
    image: 'nginx:1.15.7-alpine'
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - './docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro'
      - './:/srv/api:rw'
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
    environment:
      PLAYER_NAME: 'PLAYER_1'
    networks:
      - backend
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, you cannot do that, containers are isolated by design. You have to define the env variable for both containers.

To not duplicate your code, you can use either [yaml anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586) with [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extension-fields):

```
version: '3.7'

x-environment: &commonEnvironment
    PLAYER_NAME: 'PLAYER_1'

services:
    service-1: 
        environment: *commonEnvironment
    service-2: 
        environment: *commonEnvironment
```

or you can use env-file. Where you put all your variables in file, and reference it from docker-compose using [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)